# Huggingface model training loop has same performance on CPU & GPU? Confused as to why?

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

### Question

I created two Python notebooks to fine-tune BERT on a Yelp review dataset for sentiment analysis. The only difference between the two notebooks is that [one runs on a CPU](https://nbviewer.org/gist/AlanCPSC/f263426dce9b7b9580cd48dbc45910b0) `.to("cpu")` while the [other uses a GPU](https://nbviewer.org/gist/AlanCPSC/7f0efaeaf9b5247a80e67c9a8e0d9c8b) `.to("cuda")`.

Despite this difference in hardware, the training times for both notebooks are nearly the same. I am new to using Hugging Face, so I'm wondering if there's anything I might be overlooking. Both notebooks are running on a machine with a single GPU.

### Metrics for CPU

```
TrainOutput(global_step=100, training_loss=1.5707407319545745, metrics={'train_runtime': 116.5447, 'train_samples_per_second': 3.432, 'train_steps_per_second': 0.858, 'total_flos': 105247256985600.0, 'train_loss': 1.5707407319545745, 'epoch': 0.4})

{'eval_loss': 1.4039757251739502,
 'eval_accuracy': 0.4,
 'eval_runtime': 3.6833,
 'eval_samples_per_second': 27.15,
 'eval_steps_per_second': 3.529,
 'epoch': 0.4}

# specifically concerned with 'train_samples_per_second': 3.432
```

### Metrics for GPU

```
TrainOutput(global_step=100, training_loss=1.6277318179607392, metrics={'train_runtime': 115.46, 'train_samples_per_second': 3.464, 'train_steps_per_second': 0.866, 'total_flos': 105247256985600.0, 'train_loss': 1.6277318179607392, 'epoch': 0.4})

{'eval_loss': 1.525576114654541,
 'eval_accuracy': 0.35,
 'eval_runtime': 3.6518,
 'eval_samples_per_second': 27.384,
 'eval_steps_per_second': 3.56,
 'epoch': 0.4}

# specifically concerned with 'train_samples_per_second': 3.464
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the machine you were using had access to a GPU. The hf trainer will automatically use the GPU if it is available. It is irrelevant that you moved the model to `cpu` or `cuda`, the trainer will not check it and move your model to `cuda` if available. You can turn off the device placement with the TrainingArguments setting [no_cuda](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/en/main_classes/trainer#transformers.TrainingArguments.no_cuda):

```py
from transformers import TrainingArguments

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="./some_local_dir",
    overwrite_output_dir=True,
    per_device_train_batch_size=4,
    dataloader_num_workers=2,
    max_steps=100,
    logging_steps=1,
    evaluation_strategy="steps",
    eval_steps=5,
    no_cuda=True,
)
```

Comment: So `Trainer` is smart enough to move the model & data between devices automatically. I just have to move the model & data manually during inference? Do you know if `Trainer` is also smart enough to automatically handle multiple GPU configurations out of the box?

Comment: Question 1: Yes. Question 2: Yes. The trainer uses dataparallel as default and will use distributed parallel when used with a [launcher](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributed.html#launch-utility).