# Why cant I set TrainingArguments.device in Huggingface?

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

### Question

When I try to set the `.device` attribute to `torch.device('cpu')`, I get an error. How am I supposed to set device then?

### Python Code

```
from transformers import TrainingArguments
from transformers import Trainer
import torch

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="./some_local_dir",
    overwrite_output_dir=True,

    per_device_train_batch_size=4,
    dataloader_num_workers=2,

    max_steps=500,
    logging_steps=1,

    evaluation_strategy="steps",
    eval_steps=5
)

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=test_dataset,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
)

training_args.device = torch.device('cpu')
```

### Python Error

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-30a92c0570b8> in <cell line: 28>()
     26 )
     27 
---> 28 training_args.device = torch.device('cpu')

AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Comment: What's your transformer version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs of the [TrainingArguments](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.27.2/en/main_classes/trainer#transformers.TrainingArguments) object doesn't have a settable device attribute.

But interestingly device is initialized but non mutable:

```
import torch
from transformers import TrainingArguments

args = TrainingArguments('./')

args.device  # [out]: device(type='cpu')

args.device = torch.device(type='cpu')
```

[out]:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-dcb5ef23be68> in <cell line: 8>()
      6 
      7 
----> 8 args.device = torch.device(type='cpu')

AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

From the code, it looks like the device is set after the initialization: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/training_args.py#L1113

And the device is only setup when the `TrainingArguments.device` is called

- https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/training_args.py#L1678
- https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/training_args.py#L1524

Perhaps you are referring to the huggingface model and you want to try training it on the CPU. To do that, usually the Trainer will automatically detect it if you accelerate https://huggingface.co/docs/accelerate/index

#### By default, the `TrainingArguments` is already set to CPU if `_n_gpu = -1`

---

But if you want to explicitly set the model to be used on CPU, try:

```
model = model.to('cpu')
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=test_dataset,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
)
```

Or:

```
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model.to('cpu'),
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=test_dataset,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
    place_model_on_device=True
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to set the device in training args. The training will take place on the device of the model.
The following code should help you train your model on cpu

```
device = torch.device('cpu')
model = model.to(device)
```

`training_args.device` is an attribute which you can only read and not set, hence the error.

Comment: I don't think the statement "The training will take place on the device of the model" is correct. [Please see my other question where this is addressed.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75959314/huggingface-model-training-loop-has-same-performance-on-cpu-gpu-confused-as-t)

Comment: @AlanSTACK i checked the other question, i do not think you are setting the device correctly over there. Please use the snippet mentioned here to set your device and it should work as expected

Comment: @AlanSTACK you should try passing he torch.device to the mode.to function and not just the device string

Comment: Those method calls are the same under the hood and yield the same results.

Answer (score 0):

There is a parameter in TrainingArguments called **no_cuda**.  If you set that to True, training will take place on the CPU even if you have a GPU in your setup.  For example, the following code worked for me:

```
    # initialize the trainer
    training_args = TrainingArguments(
        output_dir='./results',
        num_train_epochs=1,
        per_device_train_batch_size=1,
        fp16=False,
        warmup_steps=500,
        weight_decay=0.01,
        logging_dir='./logs',
        prediction_loss_only=True,
        no_cuda=True
    )
    trainer = Trainer(
        model,
        training_args,
        train_dataset=tokenized_dataset["train"],
    )

    # execute the training!
    trainer.train()
```